Selenium : How to get this element's title correctly?
<h2 class="h2title">
  "title"
  <span class="h2_joyu">
    <a href="/search/actress?actress_id=1361">attress_name</a>
  </span>
</h2>

I want to extract the title of this html, what I tried is to simply write
title = dr.find_element('class name`, 'h2title').text

but what I got is both title and attress_name concatenated in the same line without space
How to get title only without touching the html below?
